# AngularJS Dynamic Template containing Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an AngularJS app which has a dynamically added form element which contains a Bootstrap popover.  When the popover is clicked, nothing pops up.  I know that popovers are 'opt-in', and have included the required Javascript in my index.html file.  However, the popover doesn't appear when clicking on the button in my template form.  If I place the popover outside the dynamic form (in index.html), the popover will show.  Any advice?

Button for Popover (index.html and phone-number.template.html):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus"
  title="Works outside of template!" 
  data-content="The popover works when not in the template form!  Odd!" >
  <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> 
</button>
```

Code to opt in (index.html):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>
```

relevant plnk: http://plnkr.co/edit/jpvafUhLd0RcAKfsrFWA?p=preview

Thanks, JR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initiating popover in document ready but it's initiating before directive load it's html. you need to initiating it on your directive load.

Add a link function put popover init there

Try like this

```
app.directive('phoneNumber', function(){
  return {
    replace:true,
     scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
    },
    templateUrl: "phone-number.template.html",
    link:function($scope,element,attrs){
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
    }
  }
});
```